# Ruby on Rails - is it correct to add additional JavaScript file in views folder directory?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, file, location, conventions

I am reading a book about "Ruby on Rails" and one of the task includes modifying the code till now, creating additional JavaScript functionality. The JavaScript itself is easy, just few lines of code, so my question is conceptual at all.

I am executing the first [activity](http://pragprog.com/wikis/wiki/Pt-F-1-31)  and in the [discussion](http://pragprog.com/wikis/wiki/Task-F-AddADashofAjax-31) folks said that the new code should be created in a separate js.erb file in the views folder.

My questions is what is the better way to solve the issue:

1. Create additional js.erb file in views folder

   **OR**
2. Add the additional JavaScript code in the
   assets->javascript->viewname.js.coffee

The people from the discussion use the second technique but is it more appropriate to add the JavaScript in the assets as it will be executed with the view?

EDIT:

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and my Rails version is 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number two is the way to go! Let the Rails 3 Asset Pipeline manage Javscript, CSS and image files for you. The `.coffee` extension is optional, depending on if you want to write in Coffeescript or not.

Comment: There's one caveat: If you want to use any server-side variables: i.e.) `alert("User with email <%= @user.email %> could not be created.");`, then you should have it as a a js.erb file in your views folder.

Comment: @niiru is there anything extra to do to get this to work? I need to use `render` in my .js.erb file, so i moved it to the Views folder, but it now seems that the asset pipeline isn't loading the file at all.

Comment: The asset pipeline won't be able to load the file because it's dynamically generated each time it's rendered (the pipeline only works for static files). You would have to add a script tag to the page you want to include the file on, which would send a request to the server to generate your JS file.